# moment.js turns everything into today

Tags: javascript, express, momentjs

I'm going crazy - the solution is probably right in front of me - but ...

```
const moment = require('moment')
moment.locale('nb')

let dato = moment(Data.datoen)
let rettDatoStart = moment.utc(dato).startOf('day').toDate()
let rettDatoSlutt = moment.utc(dato).endOf('day').toDate()
```

... logs out as:

```
2020-08-05
2020-08-06T00:00:00.000Z
2020-08-06T23:59:59.999Z
```

For the record, this is written 2020-08-06T22:57:00:000Z

What's wrong? Anyone?

**EDIT:**
I dawns on me that there is nothing wrong with this code, nor with the first suggestion. The problem, I suspect, is that this snippet is part of an async operation inside an express.js server.  I don't see why it's a problem, but some of you might?

Service.js:

```
const General = require('../../database/models/hotels/generalModel')
const Data = require('../../controller/hotels/generalController')
const moment = require('moment')
moment.locale('nb')


module.exports.getAllGeneral = async (serviceData) => {
    try {
        let dato = moment(Data.datoen)
        let rettDatoStart = moment.utc(dato).startOf('day').toString()
        let rettDatoSlutt = moment.utc(dato).endOf('day').toString()
        let generalen = await General.find({
            skaptdato: {
                $gte: rettDatoStart,
                $lte: rettDatoSlutt                 
            }
        });
        return generalen;     
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Noe gikk galt: Service: getAllGeneral', error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }  
}
```

Controller.js:

```
const generalService = require('../../service/hotels/generalService');

module.exports.getAllGeneral= async (req, res) => {  
    
    // Hent datoen fra urlen og exporter den.
    const datoen = req.query.dato;  
    exports.datoen = datoen;     

    let response = {};
    try {
        const responseFraService = await generalService.getAllGeneral(req.body);
        response.datoen = datoen;
        response.status = 200;
        response.message = 'General Hotell er hentet! [controller]';
        response.body = responseFraService;
    } catch (error) { 
        console.log('Noe gikk galt: Controller: getAllGeneral', error);
        response.status = 400;
        response.message = error.message;
        response.body = {};
    }
    return res.status(response.status).send(response);
}
```

**EDIT #2:**
Strangely,

```
let dato = moment(Data.datoen).add(1, 'day')
```

... provides the expected output - but this makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Probably because of time zones.

Comment: Don't think so. Locale is set - and the two latter logs out as the same even if "dato" is set to 2020-08-01